# Vue.js 2 Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I keep getting this same error.  My code is shown here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/88o66kkyz9

For those who need an idea of what it does, it gets lists of IPs from a websocket in the main Vue.js.   I want to create a component to layout information about the IP so I can just iterate through that in the app.vue render template  I know this is basic, but I'm really new to vue.  but god, so much better than angular messiness to me.

Comment: In IpInfo.vue, shouldn't it just be `<li>{{ip}}</li>` and not `<li>{{ip.ip}}</li>`?

Comment: ip is technically an object but let me try.Now it at least displays the entire array, I wanted the component to iterate over and over with one ip in each li

Comment: the ips variable is an object, but once you run it in the loop it no longer is passed to as an object. In any case, let me know

Comment: In response to your edited answer above, the reason why it's iterating over a new ul > li is because you have a component inside the loop passing each iterated data over as props, so each new iteration will generate a new ul list.

Comment: no, that's the thing, it's not creating more than 2 UL's.  please view this:
https://pastebin.com/S77QfF2e

Comment: I just realized I needed to iterate through the ip object twice to get what I wanted.  Perhaps because it was actually an array of objects?  I'm not sure but I think it's working.  If you post an answer, I will approve.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't need to iterate twice, but I'm also not exactly sure how you wanted things, I couldn't replicate everything because I didn't have a socket open, in any case, as long as it's working for you, great.

Comment: I also noticed that the first two entries don't show the IPs, just the ip info.  Let me post on github.
https://github.com/dkran/masscan-webui
you node app.js in the main folder, then go to npm run dev in the srv folder

Comment: https://github.com/dkran/masscan-webui
you node app.js in the main folder, then go to npm run dev in the srv folder, however it relies on nmap, and lots of regular expressions I think.  it's to detect loose ends on a network

Comment: I installed everything but sadly I'm unable to get a socket response, no errors, having a hard time replicating the issue.

Comment: You would have to npm install in the root and srv directory. Nested projects. Then at root run node app.js, then in srv type npm run dev

Comment: Were you able to figure it out @dkran?

Comment: Yes, however I have had no time to wrote it correctly, but the result is much prettier. I'll be in touch with you

Comment: Perfect, shoot me an email at iattisbarros@gmail.com if you'd like and we'll take a look.